# Block animation doesn't work on iPhone 4/4S but works on 5/5S

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am trying to animate an UIView that has some UILabels inside it. It works as expected on simulator with 4" and it does not on 3.5". I am failing to see what's wrong here as it even prints all the NSLogs with the expected values (including the one inside finished block) but doesn't animate.

I call this method from viewDidAppear.

```
-(void)animateSlidingView:(NSString *)mode
{
    NSLog(@"animateSlidingView with mode = %@", mode);

    CGRect rect;
    if ([mode isEqualToString:@"YES"])
    {
        rect = CGRectMake(-600, slidingView.frame.origin.y, slidingView.frame.size.width, slidingView.frame.size.height);
    }
    else if ([mode isEqualToString:@"NO"])
    {
        rect = CGRectMake(0, slidingView.frame.origin.y, slidingView.frame.size.width, slidingView.frame.size.height);
    }
    else
        return;

    NSLog(@"Rect = %f,%f,%f,%f,", rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void) { slidingView.frame = rect; }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
    NSLog(@"Animation Completed");
    }];

}
```

Comment: How about using a `BOOL` instead of `NSString` ? Makes life much easier.

Comment: Is autolayout turned off on the viewcontroller?

Comment: No, I can get other values, but only trigger this UIView animation on YES / NO values. My problem is that when I run on 3.5" simulator or device, it prints mode = YES or mode = NO as expected, prints the correct dimensions for rect and it even prints "Animation Completed" but it doesn't animate - visually I mean. On the other hand, it does animate on 4" simulator/device. This is odd, but it is the only noticeable thing I got so far.

Comment: autolayout is turned on

Comment: I am aware that using BOOL makes life easier. These values come from an external source so I just kept using them as they were. Anyway I switched to BOOL and the problem persists. Still got no clues on this.